# Grab nested youtube iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

I'm working on a project where I need to capture the dimensions (width and height) of YouTube embedded iframes on a webpage via an extension, specifically when the user hovers their mouse over the iframe. However, when attempting to programmatically iterate through all the iframes to obtain this information, I encounter cors policy restrictions, which prevent me from accessing the iframe's properties directly.

I've experimented with using regular expressions to circumvent this issue, but unfortunately, that approach hasn't yielded the desired results.

Can anyone provide guidance or suggest alternative methods to achieve this objective?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your own JS in the iframe and then you can use `postMessage()` to communicate between the iframe and the parent page.

If you don’t have access to the other site, your only option is to negotiate with the third party to have them add your code.